# Is functional testing different from regression testing? How?

Tags: manual-testing, regression-testing, functional

What is functional testing? is functional testing different from regression testing?
I have heard the term functional testing in many different types, some use it for thorough testing part while others say functional testing is same as regression.

I have searched many sites but there is a lots of mismatch in these.

Comment: Check this out http://www.guru99.com/. There is no mismatch.

Comment: @MuhammadAliKhamis i am aware of these different websites, but as i had written in my question, different websites shows different opinions about this. that's why i am here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Functional & Regression Testing:**

- **Functional Testing is carried** out to verify whether **implemented function or feature is working as specs** or as expected?
- Functional testing is having **scope limited to targeted feature** and functionality testing
- **Regression Testing is carried out** when bug fixes happens, features has been added in old product and that product we are planning to deploy.
- **Regression testing result helps to ensure** after bug fixes and addition of **new features** are working as expected + at the same time **previously developed features** are also **working well**
- Scope of regression testing is very wide and huge. It includes **end to end testing** of the product

Comment: That's what i was looking for, thats alot man

Answer (score 4):

Depending on where you look, you'll get slightly different answers.

**Functional Testing :**

> Testing the features and operational behavior of a product to ensure that the application is developed correspond to its specifications and requirements.

Testing that ignores the internal mechanism of a system or component and focuses solely on the outputs generated in response to selected inputs and execution conditions.
Functional tests check a particular feature for correctness by comparing the results for a given input against the specification. Functional tests don't concern themselves with intermediate results or side-effects, just the result (they don't care that after doing x, object y has state z). They are written to test part of the specification such as, "calling function Square(x) with the argument of 2 returns 4".

**Regression Testing:**

> "A regression test re-runs previous tests against the changed software to ensure that the changes made in the current software do not affect the functionality of the existing software."

Regression is surely a check against the newly deployed code/or a release deployment happened where we just make sure it has no other impacts (ex: in terms of code, functionalities, output and the behavior of the application) and therefore we ensure that deployment has been smooth.

Comment: good one Bharat !